# First time working with Apache, can't seem to setup two sites

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

First time setting up an Apache2 server with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server. I got one site working which I was quite happy with. 
Now I want to create a 2nd site on the same server and access them via internalIP/site1 and internalIP/site2

I created the directory for the 2nd site: `/var/www/html/site2` and created a .conf file named `001-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`and then  and put in:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/site2/"
    ServerName site2
</VirtualHost>
```

Then used `sudo a2ensite site2` to enable it.

The .conf file in sites/available of my site1 is `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` and looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName support
        ServerAlias support
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/osticket/

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Now the weird (to me) thing is that whenever I go to my internal IP of the server I instantly land on Site1. Maybe I changed some configuration related to this but I can't recall...I know I had to go to InternalIP/osticket (name of site1) to access it before. I can't manage to access site2 by internalIP/site2 or anything like that. I get a 404 not found error.

Keep in mind this is my first time and im trying my best to learn and provide enough information, thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

> Now the weird (to me) thing is that whenever I go to my internal IP of the server I instantly land on Site1.

This is normal. The default site is the one defined first. If you don't access the site via a hostname that the server knows about, you get the first one.

> I can't manage to access site2 by internalIP/site2

That's because `/var/www/html/osticket/site2` doesn't exist.

---

You need to access `http://site2/` instead of `http://192.168.1.123/site2/`

You are using Virtual Name Hosting. You need to use the Name.

(I made up an IP address for the sake of example).

Comment: Thanks so much, I understand what youre saying. But right now I can access site1 by going to support.intern, but I can't get to site2 by going to site2.intern. Did i miss something here?

Comment: @JaneMorning — You said `ServerName site2` not `ServerName site2.intern`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesnt work with both. we use .intern here(its set that way in the router) but site2.intern and site2 both dont work.